# how calc values in array imported from csv.reader?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have this csv file

```
Germany,1,5,10,20
UK,0,2,4,10
Hungary,6,11,22,44
France,8,22,33,55
```

and this script, 
I would like to make some aritmetic operations with values in 2D array(data)
For example print value (data[1][3])  increased of 10,
Seems that I need some conversion to integer, right ?
What is best solution please ?

```py
import csv
datafile = open('sample.csv', 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=',')

data = []
for row in datareader:
    data.append(row)
print ((data[1][3])+10)
```

I got this error

```sh
/python$ python3 read6.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read6.py", line 8, in <module>
    print ((data[1][3])+10)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Comment: "I need some conversion to integer" - yes, exactly. Do you know how to convert a string to man integer?

Comment: thanks for hint, I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually convert to integers as you suspected:

```py
import csv
datafile = open('sample.csv', 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=',')

data = []
for row in datareader:
    data.append([row[0]] + list(map(int, row[1:])))
print ((data[1][3])+10)
```

Specifically this modification on line 7 of your code:

```py
data.append([row[0]] + list(map(int, row[1:])))
```

The [csv package docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) mention that

> No automatic data type conversion is performed unless the QUOTE_NONNUMERIC format option is specified (in which case unquoted fields are transformed into floats).

Since the strings in your CSV are not quoted (i.e. `"Germany"` instead of `Germany`), this isn't useful for your case, so converting manually is the way to go.

Comment: Hi, tried your way, but I got error, I am not sure how works this way
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read7.py", line 7, in <module>
    data.append([row[0]] + map(int, row[1:]))
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "map") to list
`
so I did my way>data[1][3]=(int(data[1][3])+10)

Comment: I've updated the answer to wrap the map in a list call to avoid that error. Your approach is perfectly reasonable too though.

Comment: Thx, it work now, but can u pls explain how it works ?
specialy this data.append([row[0]] + list(map(int, row[1:])))
and what mean this ? row[1:]

Comment: Yep, the idea is to convert all items in each row to integers except the first since it's a country string (`row[0]`). `row[1:]` retrieves the sub-list of those items from the `row` list (from index 1 to the end), then `map(int, row[1:])` is a short-hand for applying the `int(...)` method to all items in that sub-list. Then we concatenate the first `row[0]` item back with the newly converted sub-list of integers with `row[0] + list(map(int, row[1:]))`. The additional `list` wrapping of `map` is necessary since `map` returns an iterator and not a list for the concat.

Comment: ok, so row[1:] mean the rest of line ? except 1st column,right ?
Works this syntax also in basic data 2D  operantions  ?

Comment: Exactly, `row[1:]` is the "slice notation" that grabs everything from index 1 to the end. You can also specify something like `row[1:5]` to stop before the end of the list. This notation only works for 1D data.

Comment: i try this > print (data[1:]) and I got output all from row 1

Comment: Yep that makes sense. The 2D `data` list is just a list of lists, so `data[1:]` will give you all lists from index 1 to the end of the outer list.

Comment: 1 more question, If I have this csv list
<code>
    Country,Index1,Index2,Index3,Index4
    Germany,1,5,10,20
    UK,0,2,4,10
    Hungary,6,11,22,44

how update your code ?>
for row in datareader:
    data.append([row[0]] + list(map(int, row[1:])))

to ignore 1st line ?
sorry for formating, but I dont know how to format Code in commenst

Comment: actualy not to ignore/exclude at all, just read as string, and your code to read int apply from 2nd line

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think you'd want something like:
```
for i, row in enumerate(datareader):
    if i == 0:
        data.append(row)
    else:
        data.append([row[0]] + list(map(int, row[1:])))
```

Comment: ok I tried it  
`for i, row in enumerate(datareader):
        if i == 0:
                data.append(row)
         else:
                data.append([row[0]] + list(map(int, row[1:])))
`
but I got this error  
` File "read11.py", line 13
    else: 
         ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
`

Comment: That's an error from Python indicating that indentation is inconsistent. Check to make sure your indentation is consistently using spaces or tabs, and that your if/else blocks are properly nested.